# how to select values from 3 tables + count()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have three Tables :

```
tbl_Publisher [Publisher_ID, addr,account-num,...,city];
tbl_Title [Title_ID, frequency, publisher,.., Publisher_ID];
tbl_Invoice [Invoice_ID, ordered_Date,...,Title_ID];
```

I would like to return a list of Titles by Publisher and each Title has the count number of Invoices it contains. in one result set.
I'm using a stored procedure as following :

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_GetTitlesbyPublisher]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @PublisherID INT


AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.


    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT Title_ID,TitleName,pub_type,Frequency , Holdings ,tbl_Title.publisher ,section ,tbl_Title.Publisher_ID  from tbl_Title, tbl_Publisher 
    where tbl_Title.Publisher_ID = tbl_Publisher.Publisher_ID
    and @PublisherID = tbl_Publisher.Publisher_ID

END
```

How can I return the number of Invoice by each Title ?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: A stored procedure using SQL Server, I added the tags needed.

Comment: But I see no sql-server tag.

Comment: I don't see enough info in the tables above but what you are looking for is GROUP BY.... I assume INVOICE_ID is in each table. You need to add COUNT(INVOICE_ID) in your SELECT and end with GROUP BY and list out all the columns you selected.

Comment: You should get in the habit of using ANSI-92 style joins, they have been around now for 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Invoice_ID only exists in tbl_Invoice as a primaryKey @logixologist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably accomplish this with a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT  t.Title_ID, t.TitleName, p.pub_type, 
        t.Frequency, Holdings, t.publisher, section, 
        t.Publisher_ID, count(i.Invoice_ID) as NoOfInvoices  
from tbl_Title t
inner join tbl_Publisher p on t.Publisher_ID = p.Publisher_ID
left join tbl_Invoice i  on i.Title_ID = t.Title_ID
where @PublisherID = p.Publisher_ID
group by t.Title_ID, t.TitleName, p.pub_type, t.Frequency, 
        Holdings, t.publisher, section, t.Publisher_ID
```

Comment: I didn't want to assume the JOINS :)

Comment: @logixologist seems to me it wouldn't make sense if they weren't `INNER JOIN`s

Comment: I agree. The OP has inner joins but in the old join style.

Comment: This only return the first record of the list, How can i return the all the titles a publisher has ?

Comment: @AyoubSalhi updated my answer to return title even if there are no invoices

Comment: Got it, I learned something today..Inner joins are useful !! @Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Not checked the syntax on this.

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_Invoice.Invoice_ID) 'InvoiceCount',Title_ID,TitleName,pub_type,Frequency, Holdings ,tbl_Title.publisher ,section ,tbl_Title.Publisher_ID  
FROM tbl_Title
INNER JOIN tbl_Publisher ON tbl_Publisher.Publisher_ID = tbl_Title.Publisher_ID
INNER JOIN tbl_Invoice ON tbl_Invoice.Invoice_ID = tbl_Title.Invoice_ID
WHERE tbl_Publisher.Publisher_ID = @PublisherID
GROUP BY
    Title_ID,TitleName,pub_type,Frequency, Holdings ,tbl_Title.publisher ,section ,tbl_Title.Publisher_ID
```

Comment: This only return one title with the count of invoices. I would like to return all the titles a publisher has.